# Applying labels to Cloud SQL , BigQuery and PubSub

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, label, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-pubsub

We need to apply labels to following `GCP Services`

```
      Cloud SQL , BigQuery and PubSub
```

The number of `Bigquery,Pubsub` services will be more than thousand across spanning across multiple `GCP projects` . We will applying the labels to all resources at one go leveraging `Python` automation using the `PATCH` method from below `APIs` .

```
   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/patch
   https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/patch
   https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/databases/patch
```

Any impact on `Cloud SQL,BigQuery and PubSub` when we apply labels to these `GCP resources` . We earlier applied `labels` to `CLoud Run and Cloud functions` where there is a corresponding `deployment and  revision/version change` when we apply the labels. We are assuming there should be any impact on `Cloud SQL,BigQuery and PubSub` services when we apply `labels`. For `PubSub` , we pushed messages to some `Topic'` and then applied labels using `API PATCH` method. After that we pulled the messages using `subscriptions` and messages are retrieved successfully .

```
  gcloud pubsub topics publish storagecheck --message "Hello2"
  gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull stcheck --auto-ack
```

Please suggest for any impact on `Cloud SQL , BigQuery and PubSub` when we apply `labels`

Comment: There is no impact on Cloud SQL, BigQuery and pubsub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will no impact on the services when we apply the labels.

Minor thing to consider is the number labels we can apply to particular instance, as of today we can assign up to 64 labels to each instance.

**Reference:**

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/label-instance

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/labels

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/labels-intro

Comment: I see there is a "UPDATE" operation when we apply labels and some spike in CPU utilization for one of the DB instances. CPU utilization went to 31.9% during this operation. Is this expected ?

Comment: Is the underlying DB is reloaded or restarted by any chance ?

Comment: There is an UPDATE that takes place when you add a label. There is nothing to worry about. The CPU spike depends on a multitude of different factors, so we can't isolate it to only the UPDATE for adding labels. When labels are added, the underlying resources are modified and not the actual Database, so you won't be having issues with serving traffic whilst you modify your Cloud SQL instance labels.